# Linear regression where the x variable is an index

Tags: regression

Say I have two series of values, $x$ and $y$, and I want to calculate their linear regression.
 If I know that $x$ is just a running index (i.e. $x_i=i$), how can I use this to simplify the normal equations for linear regression?
Specifically, since the slope is just $c_{xy} \cdot {\sigma_y \over \sigma_x} $, if I'd have a simple expression for the correlation $c_{xy}$ (where $x$ is a running index) it'll be enough.

Comment: In practice regression software is very fast and very stable. You could spend more time trying to write efficient code for this special case than you would ever save in practice.

Comment: I know. This is more of a theoretical question.

Comment: It sounds like $y$ is a signal. Therefore, it's likely that you have correlated errors and don't meet the assumptions for linear regression. To find the appropriate test of autocorrelation, or to to find the correct way to measure a linear trend in a signal, a few questions need to be asked of your dataset. This might lead to, for example, an Autocorrelated Errors Model (Ch 16 of Learning and Practicing Econometrics by Griffiths et al, 1993), which is more advanced than the usual simple linear regression and might suit your problem better.

Comment: $y$ is indeed a sort of a signal, and its (rolling) trend-line is only part of the analysis. I tried to keep my question focused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got by myself:

The definition $c_{xy}⋅{σ_x \over σ_y}$ is already equal to $cov(x,y)\over σ^2_x$, so all we need is a simpler expression for $cov(x,y)$ when $x$ is an index. 
Now, $cov(x,y)=∑^N_{i=0}(x_i−\bar x)(y_i−\bar y)$, where $x=i$ in my question.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that there's an odd number of points (so $N$ is even), so we can reindex them from $−N/2$ to $N/2$ instead of $0$ to $N$. 
 Let $n=N/2$, we have: $cov(x,y)=∑^n_{i=−n}i(y_i−\bar y) = ∑^n_{i=−n}iy_i$ (the second term in the sum vanishes), which can be further reduced to $cov(x,y) = ∑^n_{i=1}2i \cdot (y_i-y_{-i})$.

Knowing the the variance $\sigma^2$ is equal to ${N^2-1}\over 12$, the result is just $ {12 \over {N^2-1}} \sum^{N/2}_{i=1} 2i \cdot (y_{N/2+i}-y_{N/2-i}) $ (in the original indices).

Comment: Thank you! Readers might also be interested in your explanatino here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98001/calculating-slope-between-pixels-through-time-using-arcpy/98223#98223

Comment: I implemented this and the calculated slope is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure out how you derived the last part with that $2i$ and I failed.
It seems also you are not considering $N$ or maybe $N-1$ for the covariance.
During my PhD I had faced the same problem and what I had ended up with was:

$\frac{12}{N(N^{2}-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{(N-1)/2} i(y_{i_{0}+i}-y_{i_{0}-i})$

with $ i_{0} $ being the median value's index in the original set.
Those who have problems with your approach can give this a try.

Comment: The $N$ vs $N-1$ issue is irrelevant--you are referring to a different formula for a different situation.  Your answer looks incorrect because it doesn't scale properly: for instance, if you were to duplicate all the data the sum would approximately quadruple but the factor in front would become about one-eighth of its original value, shrinking the slope estimate by a factor of 2, whereas duplicating the data ought to produce essentially the same estimate as before.

Comment: I updated the form of how exactly I was using it and it was working. $ i_{o} $ is the index of a median value in the original set. If you have already transformed the indices putting the median index to 0, then this is basically gone. In my case, I had to use the sample covariance. For the population covariance one could go with just $N$. $N$ is the amount of sequential data points in the original set.

Comment: small correction above: * "The index of the median value". 

Also, if you were duplicating the data, the increase in the summation would depend on the slope, because on every extra iteration step, the multiplier $i$ not only becomes weighter but also, the difference between the first and last value in the set increases more and more. This approach had been examined next to the normal way of slope computation. And it was always resulting in the same outcome (but faster ofc).

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example of some numbers where this fails to calculate correctly the underlying slope. Cause what I only have is that I remember it was working. (I was using it as a metric to detect convergence within a rolling window of values)

Comment: I actually tried yesterday to apply Mushkin's approach out of curiosity cause it looks more elegant. But I failed. Either I do not understand how his formula works, or it doesn't work.

Comment: You are correct that there are (multiple) errors in their formula (even though the approach is a good one).

Comment: @whuber if you don't want to spend the time/effort to edit it, you can point me to the general direction of the errors and I'll try to edit it clearly myself.

Comment: @Itamar apply your formula to a simple case and go on from there.